# How to migrate blockchain data from Moonbeam network to a custom Substrate-based chain?

Tags: migration

I deployed an ERC-721(NFT) contract on Moonbeam some time ago. Now I have added the NFT pallet to our Substrate-based chain.

How can I migrate the data from the Moonbeam network chain data to our chain?

Any suggestion helpful. Thanks

Comment: To understand it better, you want to migrate all the data that this contract has produced in your new chain?

Comment: Yes, I want to migrate all data.

Comment: They are a lot of details. This might help you https://medium.com/darwinianetwork/first-successfully-merge-of-substrate-solo-chain-and-polkadot-parachain-2da40069b6a7.